# Javascript get element including double curly braces

Tags: javascript

I need to get an element and store it into a variable as string.

HTML:

```
<div id="my-element"><span>{{content}}</span></div>
```

JS:

```
var template = document.getElementById('my-element').innerHTML;
console.log(template); //returns empty element in console
```

like this:

```
<span></span>
```

But the expected is:

```
<span>{{content}}</span>
```

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementsById`

Comment: console.log(template.innerHTML); ?

Comment: My code was wrong. Check again.

Comment: I get the expected result. https://jsfiddle.net/sf9yx7b6/ What browser are you using? maybe the `{{content}}` is just hidden on the console? try doing an `alert` and see if it is there.

Comment: Are you using any libraries such as Polymer?

Comment: @MarcCompte I'm using Chrome. I tested in JSfiddle and it works, but in Chrome doesn't.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Did you try doing an `alert(template)` and see if you see it ok there? Maybe it is just something particular to Chrome's console and the data is actually there. Or maybe some other code in your page messes it up. In any case, that code seems to be working fine.

Comment: @MarcCompte Yes, I tried using `alert(template)` but returns only `<span></span>`

Comment: @gcampbell I'm not using libraries.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I put eveything into an html and run it in Firefox and Opera (don't have Chrome on this machine) and it still works as expected. Does this work for you if you paste it into a blank html file? `<div id="my-element"><span>{{content}}</span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var template = document.getElementById('my-element').innerHTML;
console.log(template); //returns empty element in console
alert(template);
</script>`

Comment: It works perfectly even in Chrome. I'm not using javascript libraries but I use Grunt im my worflow. Maybe the problem is in some step of the process, like serve/livereload.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you have a typo in `getElementsById`

But this should work for you:

```js
var template = document.getElementById('my-element');
console.log(template.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="my-element"><span>{{content}}</span></div>
```

Comment: The result must contain the span tag: <span>{{content}}</span>

Comment: Did you run the snippet? It does. Look at the console (gray bar at the bottom of the snippet)

Comment: Yes, I ran the snippet, but using directly on chrome, doesn't works.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Please see this.

```
var template = document.getElementById('my-element');
console.log(template);




<div id="my-element"><span>{{content}}</span></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nazmul_sylhet/rpn921ea/1

Comment: the result must contain the span tag: <span>{{content}}</span>